# NVIDIA drivers installed - but not in use on Ubuntu (Studio) 16.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 16.10, ubuntu-studio

After searching for possible solutions and trying many different things without any success, I decided to ask the community.

I recently built a computer containing a GTX 1050 ti. After installing Ubuntu Studio 16.04 and installing NVIDIA drivers (before they were not shown in the additional drivers list), I tried to play 'Kerbal Space Program', but the performance of the main menu and the start up process of the program were very slow.

I couldn't see the NVIDIA drivers in the Additional drivers tab of settings application, but after adding some other repositories, I finally now can see these three drivers options there: [Additional drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jcug.png)

I tried both of them in my subsequent test `glmark2`. Both times GL_RENDERER was displayed as `Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe`. From my online research (and the glmark2 score of 291), I figured out that the NVIDIA drivers are not being used, even though the NVIDIA drivers were selected in the list of Additional drivers. Here are the outputs from `lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12` and `lshw` ->

```
lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [10de:1c82] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [10de:11bf]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_375_drm, nvidia_375

lshw -class display
*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GP107
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:16 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable the `nouveau` drivers - to do it open a terminal and execute the following command :

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to this line -> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

that it now reads -> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to close the file and confirm the change you have made by pressing <kbd>Y</kbd>.

Now update the GRUB boot configuration to make this setting active : `sudo update-grub`

Reboot the operating system, now you use the NVIDIA drivers and `nouveau` is deactivated.

**Update addressing your comment that `Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe` is still shown :**

Keep the GRUB boot configuration change you've made.

Boot the computer and uninstall the NVIDIA drivers ...

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*
sudo poweroff
```

Boot the computer and re-install the NVIDIA drivers ...

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-375
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Will definitely try this out when I can. I thought I had already tried disabling nouveau, but not this way. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, my problem does not seem to be resolved.

This is the grub file after reboot:

http://pastebin.com/FTvWTeUdT

Running the glmark2 shows again the Gallium 0.4....

Comment: Well I got it to work, by blacklisting the gallium drivers and then activating the nvidia-378 via the Additional Drivers screen.